# Allow remote urls in Dolphin "Open File" dialog

Tags: linux-mint, kde-plasma-5, dolphin-file-manager

I have recently switched from Windows to Linux (mint 18.2 with KDE, using Dolphin as file manager). I have noticed that when using the "open file" dialog (or upload file) in any external application you can't choose a remote url as source from the file

[image: Remote file upload]

In windows, if i paste an url as file source for file upload it gets uploaded just fine, here the "open" button is disabled (i know the image i typed does not exist but it's disabled even with an existing image)

Is there some way to do this on linux too? since i often upload images from the web into other websites this feature was very handy

Comment: I had this for a time in Ubuntu 16.04 Mate with Caja file manager, but it seems to have been sorted during some of the updates. I am now on 16.04.3 LTS and it is working as before. Maybe there are some updates which will take care of your problem.

Comment: I have Dolphin loaded on my system. When I put a web-hosted image URL into Dolphin's address bar, I got an error line in Dolphin saying `Dolphin does not support web pages, the web browser has been launched`: Konqueror was then launched and the image appeared in it. This is not the same as your Open dialogue, but it suggests that your dialogue may work on current releases. My Dolphin release is 14.12.3 and Konqueror is 4.14.16.

Comment: What if you go into, for example, whatsapp or facebook and try uploading an image, when the open dialog appears then you press "CTRL + L" to open the location bar and paste an URL?

Comment: I don't use FaceBook. It doesn't work with WhatsApp Web, nor SuperUser with the local up-load option using PaleMoon (my default browser). I have tried SuperUser on FireFox, Chromium and Konqueror, and local up-load doesn't work on any of them, but it does work with the open dialogue on some other applications, eg my default image browser Eye of Mate and the KDE-based Okular, but not Shotwell nor Gimp. It is too much hassle to switch WhatsApp Web to other browsers, so I haven't checked this. I don't regularly use other up-load sites.

Comment: When you put a URL into a file open dialog, Windows transparently downloads it into your profile as a "temporary internet file" and opens it from there. I have no answer for your question, but this info may be interesting to you.

Comment: @Corrodias any way to emulate the same behavior?